# How to use use two loops parallel, Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, upload, callback, sftp

I am working on motion detection application in Raspberry Pi. There is a python script which should check output of `c++` code and if "alert" is printed, it should start to upload images from a given directory to server:

```
for line in self.output:
  if line == "alert\n":
    # upload a frame from directory to a server
```

However, each frame takes around 30 seconds to upload to a server, but each new line is printed out in 500ms. So, it is not efficient at all to wait for uploading current frame in each `if` condition of `for` loop.

I am new to Python. Is there any way to run two methods parallel? I know about threads, but I am not sure what would happen if `for` loop creates new thread each time in Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You should start a **single** new thread and have a queue of operations for it to complete.  This means that the operations will complete in sequence without blocking your main thread.

Comment: follow this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies

Answer (score 0):

each time you execute a the if statement a thread will be created, it would execute and then stop(if the thread itself doesn't have a loop). you can use the following syntax.

```
    def myFunc():
         #does the stuff you want it to do 
    for line in self.output:
       if line == "alert\n":
          threading.Thread(target=myFunc,args=randomArgs)
```